# Vector of trainable parameters for custom activation function

Tags: python, parameters, keras, activation

I am kind of new to Keras, and am trying to run some experiments with a custom activation function that has a trainable parameter. I have created the code below which is essentially a variation of the ReLU activation function. It currently computes `alpha*h1 + (1 - alpha)*h2` where `h1 = relu(x)` and `h2 = relu(-x)`, in hopes to help with dead neurons that the regular ReLU function can create. I was wondering if instead of just having this one trainable parameter `alpha`, if it were possible to amend this code to produce a vector of trainable parameters to test this idea further with. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class CustomLayer(Layer):
  def __init__(self, alpha, **kwargs):
    self.alpha = alpha
    super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                  shape=(input_shape[1], self.alpha),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
    super(CustomLayer, self).build(input_shape)

  def call(self,x):
    h1 = K.relu(x)
    h2 = K.relu(-x)
    return self.kernal*h1 + (1 - self.kernal)*h2

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], self.alpha)
```

Comment: I think I fixed the indentation in your code but please take a look and make sure. Also, something to be aware of when posting code on here: indentation is important in Python; check that it's correct.

Comment: Does `shape=(..., self.alpha)` make sense? Shape takes a tuple of integers, and I don't get the feeling that this is what `alpha` should be used for.

Comment: @Engineero thank you, the indentation is now correct. Also, for your other question. I was trying to mimic what they did here https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/ on Keras' website, but could have implemented something incorrectly.

Comment: Yeah, in the example you link the input to the layer is still a dimension, so it makes sense to pass it to the `shape` argument. In this case that doesn't make sense since `alpha` is a (presumably floating-point) parameter, not something describing the shape of your data.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- You are currently setting the output shape of your network with `alpha`, which is almost certainly not correct.
- You can define the kernel for your layer to be whatever size makes sense for what you are trying to do. This is where you want to create the trainable parameters for your activation function.
- Since this is an activation function, you probably want the output to be the same shape as the input.

Try something like:

```
from keras import backend as K

class CustomLayer(Layer):
    # You actually don't need to redefine __init__ since we don't need to
    # pass any custom parameters. I'm leaving it here to show that it changed
    # from your example.
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], 1),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      trainable=True)
        super(CustomLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        h1 = K.relu(x)
        h2 = K.relu(-x)
        return h1*self.kernal + h2*(1 - self.kernel)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

I am assuming you want a different `alpha` parameter for each feature in your input vector, which is what I create in the `build()` method. I am also assuming that `input_shape = [batch_size, num_features]` or something similar. The `call()` method performs element-wise multiplication between your `h1` and `h2` and the kernel, adding the two halves together. Basically the same cost function with a unique `alpha` for every feature.

There might be a little bit of debugging you'll need to do for this as I don't have an example on which to run it.

Here's the link to the documentation on [writing your own layers](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/), which you seem to already have but I am including here for completeness.